# Call SignalR Hub From Another .Net Project

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, .net-core-3.1

I've got `SignalR` hubs in one .`NetCore` project and `SignalR` clients in another .`NetCore` project (to comply with internal infrastructure guidelines).  I'm struggling with how to implement the client code that will provide the connection to the hubs.  All my projects build fine, I'm just missing the connectivity part.

Client Project:

```
public class MyClientController
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<MyHub, IMyHubClient> _hub;

        public MyClientController(IHubContext<MyHub, IMyHubClient> hub)
        {
            _hub = hub;
            // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED/HIT BECAUSE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO REGISTER IT
            _hub.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage("Notify", $"Hello everyone.  This has been constructed");
        }
}
```

I'm guessing I need to do some configuration in the `Startup.Configure()` method?  I've installed the client package already,

EDIT: I added the following code, but it's complaining about the format (remember, this is not a relative path, it's in another service).

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("http://localhost:60913/myHub");
}
```

Am I on the right path here?

Comment: The hub class and the routing have to live within the same app context. You can't arbitrarily map to some other server endpoint -- what would it talk to? Mapping means "for all connections coming to me (this app) on this path, answer with this hub class".

Comment: @NoahStahl...I pretty sure a .Net client living on Server A can call a .Net Hub living on Server B.  Unless I lost my mind (possible), I did this same thing several years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is made by mapping a route to your hub class. The [docs have a good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-and-use-hubs). This includes:

```
// Add to services collection
services.AddSignalR();
```

```
// Map the route "/chathub" to a ChatHub class
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
});
```

By the way, a hub can be a standalone class not associated to a controller.

Comment: I don't see that in the docs.  Are you referring to something like - endpoints.MapControllerRoute(...

Comment: Okay, but how's it going to know the URI of the hubs?

Comment: It's defined by the pattern relative to the base URL. "/chathub" means clients would connect to https://myapp.com/chathub. Hubs are separate from controllers.

Comment: The hubs are in one project/service and the clients in another.  They don't exist on the same server.